# Anyone know Chrome's "Unique name"?

Tags: xml, google-chrome, scroll, zooming

I'm trying to replace the zoom functionality with scroll on my microsoft ergonomic keyboard 7000. Since intellitype's command.xml doesn't have chrome listed and I've changed all the other attributes associated with zoom to no avail. I would just like to manually add it but I'm not sure what the unique name is. Here is what I have for internet explorer.

```
    <Application UniqueName="IEFrame7" AppName="Internet Explorer 7.0 and 8.0">
        <C308 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl o" />
        <C310 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl p" />
        <C311 Type="5" KeySeq="alt p | a" />
        <C315 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl f" />
        <C401 Type="0" />
        <C100 Type="1" wParam="0x0a121" />
        <C101 Type="1" wParam="0x0a122" />
        <C102 Type="1" wParam="0x0a220" />
        <C106 Type="2" lParam="0x07" />
        <C104 Type="2" lParam="0x05" />
        <C105 Type="2" lParam="0x06" />
        <C319 Type="6" Activator="ScrollUp" /> 
        <C320 Type="6" Activator="ScrollDown" /> 
        <C309 Type="6" Activator="IE7Close" />
        <C307 Type="6" Activator="IE7New" />
    </Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://rephrase.net/days/08/intellitype-xml) (search for "UniqueName") on [rephrase.net](http://rephrase.net/) :

> UniqueName is the important one, and refers to the window class name
>   passed to the relevant [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633586%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions. If you want to do
>   application-specific customisation, there's third-party software
>   around (e.g. [The Customiser](http://www.searchlores.org/tools.htm)) that can get a class name from any active
>   window. If not, the special UniqueName value "StandardSupport" applies
>   to all window classes.

Googling for "chrome wndclass" (from the API docs) turns up http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_27417954.html which (scroll down!) has the following possible values:

```
Chrome_WidgetWin_0
Chrome_OmniboxView
Chrome_AutocompleteEditView
```

while [Stealing a window into a CreateWindow window creates a "frozen" window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988233/stealing-a-window-into-a-createwindow-window-creates-a-frozen-window) suggests

```
Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

I guess these are all different windows that could be affected.  Maybe one is the main window for web pages?  Otherwise you could try using one of the customizer programs linked (it's not clear to me which to use).

PS Or you could use "StandardSupport" for everything.